# Thermodynamics, Phase change diagrammes

Tags: thermodynamics, pressure, temperature, volume, phase-diagram

What would be the phenomena and PV, TV diagrammes for a closed vessel partially filled with water and subjected to heat, How change in vapour pressure would effect its boiling?, How PV, TV diagrammes would be modefied for this situation. I have 
to achieve 30 bar pressure and 200C temperature and then have to mantain these conditions for 2 hours.

Comment: What are you referring to when you ask about "the phenomena"?

Comment: You want to analyze the equilibrium conditions in a closed container partially filled with liquid water and with water vapor, given the container volume and the amount of water as a function of the temperature, correct?

Comment: yes, i want to analyze equilibrium conditions partially filled with water and water vapor. Moreover i also want to analyze that how boiling will happen as due to heat given vapor pressure will rise hence boiling point will also rise. how PV, TV diagrammes will look like? In my problem volume of vessel is 2 ltr and half filled with water initially. Thanks.

Comment: The pressure and temperature of your container will follow the Antoine equation for water.  In addition, an energy balance will tell you the rate of temperature rise.  For much more info, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antoine_equation

Comment: Are you familiar with using the steam tables?

Comment: Thank-you Chet Miller, Yes i'm familiar with steam tables. in my case PV or TV diagrammes would get modified. As example temperature of vessel remains higher then saturation temperature at respective pressure in my case.

Comment: Thankyou David White, please elaborate that how energy balance will be applied here in my case. thanks

Comment: How is the temperature of the vessel be made to remain higher than the saturation temperature at the respective pressure in your case?

Comment: Chet Miller, u r right but this thing happening in my equipment. and im unable to understand that why temperature remains higher then sat temp at respwctive pressure.